# Android Studio sometimes fails to launch app on phone from virtual machine

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using android studio in an Ubuntu VM in Virtualbox on a Linux Mint host. 
I'm able to connect my s5 to the vm and compile then launch the app on my phone. However, sometimes (usually after 2 or 3 prior launches) I will select run, android studio will finish building but then nothing happens. The app does not launch but it shows my phone is still connected. The way I have to fix this (as retrying does not work) I disconnect phone from vm, reconnect phone and restart android studio then the app launches on first try. It seems like a problem with android studio since the only way to get out of it is to restart but I'm not sure how to prevent this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i also face this problem but i fix it by reinstalling the app

Comment: Do you mean you uninstall the app before you try to launch it from android studio and then it works?